# Documentation for multiple display app development

Tags: android, mobile

This one is fairly quick, but I am hopeful someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

I recently purchased an LG Wing and am trying to find some good resources that explain how exactly to develop an extended application that uses both screens at the same time.

So far I havent been able to find any decent resources, and honestly think I may be using all the wrong terminology.

If anyone has had a similar experience and could possibly share the content that they found helpful to get into this kind of mobile development it would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know exactly what LG did for the Wing. For other types of external displays, such as monitor that you plug in via HDMI, you can use `DisplayManager` to find the display. From there, you could use `Presentation` or `ActivityOptions` to arrange to display content there.

Comment: Looks like LG had a custom SDK: https://web.archive.org/web/20210508221223/https://mobile.developer.lge.com/develop/lgwing/lgwing_sdk/ but archive.org didn't get the SDK as you needed be authorized to download. Sadly LG wiped the site at the end of 2021: https://web.archive.org/web/20211208133054/https://mobile.developer.lge.com/